# Edittext inside ExpandableListView does not show keyboard

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom DialogFragment thats displays an ExpandableListView and its items are EditText.
When the EditText gets the focus the input keyboard is not shown, even if I force it by code using the InputMethodManager.FORCED flag.

DialogFragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
>

...

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"

     />

<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#FF0000"
           android:text="@string/no_calculations"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Item XML of the Expanded List:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:background="#ffffff" >
 .....

 <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editTextPercentage"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/percentageSymbol"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"           
       android:maxLength="8"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
       android:text="@string/default_percentage_calculations" >
 </EditText> 
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Even forcing the keyboard, it also does not work:

```
final EditText percentage=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextPercentage);
percentage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)  getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   imm. showSoftInput (percentage, InputMethodManager. SHOW_FORCED);
   return false;
}
      });
```

Any idea how I can show the keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround, its really a trick because I don't really know why does it work.
I just added a dummy invisible Edittext at the beginning of DialogFragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
>

<EditText
       android:id="@+id/dummyEditText"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal"            
        android:enabled="false"
        android:visibility="gone"
       />
......
```

Comment: but what if you close the keyboard, can the keyboard reappear when you click on the EditText?